# В чем разница использования ViewModel и DTO классов?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Предположим у нас есть следующий классы

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int RequestTypeId {get;set;}
    public DateTime OpeningDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime? ClosingDate {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<RequestHistory> History {get;set;}
}

public class RequestHistory
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int RequestId {get;set;}
    public int RequestStateId {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp { get;set;}
}
```

для различных действий с бизнес объектом(создание, редактирования, т.п.) у меня есть *другие* классы:

```
public class CreateRequest
{    
    public int RequestTypeId {get;set;}
    public DateTime OpeningDate {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
}

public class EditRequest
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int RequestStateId {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
}
```

Где то в *сервисном слое* я преобразовываю классы `CreateRequest`, `EditRequest` в `Request` и `RequestHistory`.

В приложении создаваемом по умолчанию, подобные классы имеют *префикс* **ViewModel**, так же в этих классах настраиваются атрибуты валидации(Обязательность, минимальная/максимальная длинна, т.п.).

Среди шаблонов проектирования есть так называемый шаблон проектирования[DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO):

> используется для передачи данных между подсистемами приложения. Data Transfer Object, в отличие от business object или data access object не должен содержать какого-либо поведения.

Объясните пожалуйста для чего и в каких случаях необходимо использовать тот или иной способ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница в названиях же. Я больше по `WPF` с этим сталкивался, так что в его рамках пример.

Я передаю с сервера на клиент данные о чем угодно. Это `DTO`, оно и предназначено для передачи.
На клиенте переданные данные я форматирую, комбинирую, подстраиваю под формат отображения. Получается `ViewModel`.

Например, с сервера пришел список писем. Письма тут - явные `DTO`.
А потом на клиенте я уже отображаю метки у писем, отображаю признаки важности, заголовки, вложения - это уже обычная `ViewModel`. Конечно, можно нагрузить этим сервер и заставить его формировать модель отображения - клиенту будет легче. Но, так вы ограничиваете возможности клиента и поддержку других клиентов сразу же.

Comment: получается в моем случае `CreateRequest`, `EditRequest` это `ViewModel`, тогда мне не понятно что есть `DTO`, не могли бы Вы привести пример класса который будет `DTO` в таком случае. если я правильно понял то сначала Мы `DAO` преобразуем в `DTO` а из `DTO` делаем получается `ViewModel`, так?

Comment: @Bald визуально - и то и другое у вас вполне тянет на DTO. Делите по логике - контекст отображения это вью_модель, классы для передачи - DTO.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewModel** - класс являющийся прослойкой связывающей View и Model/Business Logic.

**DTO** - Data Transfer Object, собственно, не имеющая логики модель.

Во ViewModel Вы можете использовать DTO как источник данных для обработки  или отображения. А наоборот нет :)